# How to draw a line on a panel after pack() has been called?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I am writing a small GUI in Java, using Swing components. My program uses several overlapping panels, the sizes of which are decided upon at the point that 'pack()' is called.

My problem is this. I need to know the dimensions of a particular `JPanel` prior to `pack()`, as I need to draw a line vertically down it. I cannot get this height dimension however until pack is called.

I have put in a `System.out.println(myPanel.getSize())` call before the pack command & it returns `(0, 0)`. When put in after, it returns the actual dimensions of the panel... as you would expect.

So, how does one draw a line on a panel down its entire length, either without knowing its length to begin with, or somehow doing so after pack has been called?

Comment: *"draw a line on a panel down its entire length"* DYM on the left hand side or RHS of the panel, or somewhere in between the two? What is the purpose of this line? What does it provide to the end user?

Comment: The line is there to act as a 'bracket', or it will eventually. I want to create 'square brackets' on either side of a rectangular JPanel. So, I thought, could either put actual images there or draw them in. I decided to attempt to draw them.

Comment: *"So, I thought, could either put actual images there or draw them in. I decided to attempt to draw them."* I'd go for Option 'C'. A custom `JComponent` (a `BracketComponent`) that accepts a constant in the constructor (`Bracket.LEFT` or `Bracket.RIGHT`) to decide which way to render. The custom component would return a preferred size to give the layout hints as to how large to render it, but when called to render, it would use the space that has been assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding a `ComponentListener` to the panel. Its `componentResized()` event is triggered whenever the panel is resized. And inside `componentResized()` method you will always get the actual size of the panel. Try below example and see it yourself.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

public class PanelResize
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    CustomPanel panel = new CustomPanel();
    panel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()
    {
      @Override
      public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
      {
        System.out.println(panel.getSize());
        panel.repaint();
      }
    });

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(panel);
    f.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel
{
  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawLine(getWidth()/2, 0, getWidth()/2, getHeight());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to do what I was looking for.